# File deletion using a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, pdf-reader

My thread cannot delete PDF files. When I debug this solution, the file is deleting. In service mode, it is not deleting.

This is my sample code:

```
Thread Worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start)); //Main Function
Worker.Start();

public void Start()
{
    string text=PDFToText(@"C:\1.pdf");
    File.Delete(@"C:\1.pdf");
}

private string PDFToText(string filename) // My PDF reader function
{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(filename);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    string text = stripper.getText(doc);
    doc.close();
    return text;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an exception or something?

Comment: No.I have no exception...

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: I guess this is not an error with deleting a file using a thread, but currently the file is in use when the thread called it.

Comment: Could you add a Catch Exception Message to see if an error occurs?

Comment: So it silently fails to delete the file?  That's a little bizarre.  Have you looked in the system event log to see if the service threw an Exception?

Comment: Is "service mode" the same as a "Release build"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is possibly happening is that something (probably the API you are using) has a lock on the file, preventing the delete.

When you do this in debug and step through, because you're *stepping* through it at a "slow" pace, the lock has been released, and the file is successfully deleted.

You should put the deletion code in a retry loop with an exception handler, which sleeps for a second or so and then tries again, giving OS a chance to relinquish the lock.

Another thing to consider is that, assuming you are running this as a service when in production, the service is running under a different user-account than when you debug it through visual studio (assuming you are not attaching to the service - it's hard to tell here).  Check that the account the service is running under has permissions to delete the file in the first place.